# I can’t run the demo flutter app on live device

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

When I run demo app for first time in Flutter VS Code editor. It gives me an error.I am using LG G5 with Oreo 8.0.0 as device for testing. I am attaching screenshot of error and the build.gradle file. Please help.

Here are image links which I have also posted on Hashnode

- https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image/upload/v1589211939604/MGPN2sCOe.png?auto=format&q=60
- https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image/upload/v1589211949952/SbEQUkqXr.png?auto=format&q=60
- https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image/upload/v1589211951887/cWCdiB6PS.png?auto=format&q=60

Comment: This happens when we are running an app for the first time as Gradle is being downloaded and if there is some problem with the internet(slow or inconsistent internet) then this error occurs. Try restarting the app again.

Comment: I changed the API level to 28. Still facing the issue. The gradle is downloaded.